# What's the title of a book about a startup which writes bioware for eyes?

Tags: story-identification, novel, nanotechnology

Please identify this book where the protagonist is a programmer who writes software/bioware for eyes. His startup company is working on a newer version of the bioware and is in a race with the competition to get to the market faster.

I read it about 5-7 years ago. The main character is this guy who has the idea for the bioware. Supporting characters are a smart but beautiful (of course..) partner and another geek. The story went through the software/bioware development as well as funding and marketing. They are working with a bioware commodity board that looks like stock market. I'll add more as I remember it.

Answer (score 6):

Your story seems to be part of the plot of [David Edelman's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Louis_Edelman) *Jump 225* trilogy (*Infoquake*, *Multireal*, *Geosynchron*). It's about a guy, with a smart and beautiful partner and another geek, who writes bio-software and fights hard with competition and with a somewhat tyrannic government. It all starts with augmented vision, but it develops into a kind of bio-software which enables to actually see the possible futures and choose among them.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks pamatt.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I really enjoyed reading Infoquake. I read the other two books a few year after the first, and I got somewhat disappointed with the way the story evolved. But I'd reccommend the trilogy anyway, for Edelman did a great job creating the social and historical environment of his characters and conceiving amazing evolutions of bioware.

Comment: @DanSarr: When you return to the site, can you accept the answer?